# Example for use tinymce in wordpress 3.5.1?

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I'm search the topic about how to use tinymce in wordpress 3.5.1 and i not found.
I'm writing plugin and i have textarea that i want to add timymce into What should i do to add tinymce into suppose that i have textarea like this

```
<textarea class="focus_des" name="focus_des" id="focus_des" ></textarea>
```

Comment: You should use [`wp_editor()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) to create TinyMCE instances.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wp_editor()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1807). There are many configuration options; you have to read the source to get all of them.

Example:

```
$editor_settings =  array (
    'textarea_rows' => 15,
    'media_buttons' => FALSE,
    'teeny'         => TRUE,
    'tinymce'       => TRUE,
    'dfw'           => FALSE,
);

$content = $get_option( 'your_option_name' );
wp_editor( $content, 'your_editor_id', $editor_settings );
```